# Group by to different columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have customer data in a table structure like this:

```
customerID | status       | 
xxx        | 1            |
xxx        | 2            | 
yyy        | 3            |
xxx        | 1            |
yyy        | 4            |
yyy        | 4            |
```

I would now like to see the different status each customer have

So the result would be:

```
customerID | status1     |  status2      |  status3      |  status4
xxx        |  2          | 1             |  0            | 0
yyy        |  0          | 0             |  1            | 2
```

Comment: How many different status do you have?

Comment: @McNets In that case lets say i have only 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (customerID varchar(10), status int);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('XXX', 1),
('XXX', 2),
('XXX', 3),
('YYY', 2),
('YYY', 2),
('XXX', 1),
('XXX', 4),
('YYY', 4);
```

If there are a well-known different `status` values, you can use a PIVOT solution in this way:

```
SELECT customerID, [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(
    SELECT customerID, status FROM tbl
) src
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(status) FOR status IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) pvt;
```

Result:

```
customerID |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4
:--------- | -: | -: | -: | -:
XXX        |  2 |  1 |  1 |  1
YYY        |  0 |  2 |  0 |  1
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8a4d9cf6df04349ae263ede5ac5e31d)*

Or you can use SUM(CASE WHEN status = ...)

```
SELECT customerID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Status1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Status2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Status3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Status4
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY customerID;
```

Result:

```
customerID | Status1 | Status2 | Status3 | Status4
:--------- | ------: | ------: | ------: | ------:
XXX        |       2 |       1 |       1 |       1
YYY        |       0 |       2 |       0 |       1
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c2faf0d1fa4d41059bbdd83f347a3e6d)*

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is there another way of doing this without PIVOT?

Comment: Added to the answer